# How to connect a relay to 220 Volts outlet?

Tags: ac, relay, control, socket, outlet

I used relays before but just for simple 5V DC signals control using a Raspberry Pi. Now I'm quite cautious and would like to ask for some help from professionals because I'm not planning to set my apartment on fire.

**What do I currently know about this?**

I currently use the relay to switch on/off my computers. Doing this is very simple. Since computers turn on by shorting two terminals, I just took a branch from the power buttons of my computers and hooked them to a relay (like the one in the picture) to the terminals are not connected by default. I have a little script that switches the relay for 0.5 seconds, which is enough to turn computer on.

[image]

**The problem:**

Now I would like to use this to control some 220 Volts power outlet. For that, I bought a socket, like the one in the picture, and mounted it on a plastic project box:

[image]

From that socket comes 3 terminals, two terminals (call them black and red) and earth in the middle (call it green).

I would like to install an IEC socket on the box, too (like the one in the following picture):

[image]

**The question:**

How should I connect the outlet socket to the IEC through the relay? Please advise.

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: You should use cables

Comment: You need a relay or contactor rated for mains, with the right part it's as straightforward as a 5v relay with some extra due diligence to securing/isolating mains carrying wires. There are also solid state relays that will work. If you want to control mains power there are other devices like triacs and scrs that can be used

Comment: @crasic Triacs and scrs are not a great idea, since they have off leakage and an external user can assume off=off and kill themselves. As for what to use in stead: Not only do you need a rated relay, but it also needs to be on a well designed board, not like the cheap eBay crap. And it needs to disconnect both wires.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I thought that's kind of given... are you serious?

Comment: I'd be interested to see specs on the relay board.  The relay specs look good but the diode (and other parts) may not be rated for mains AC.

Comment: @David This is the relay board: http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00M8XJ71U?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: you have everything else, so, what is missing? Or are you going to tell me you just had an epiphany to buy these components without having any idea to wire them together to do whatever you want?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Read the first paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a properly rated relay, you don't need to do anything fancy. Just use the right gauge wire for your power requirements.

Route the hot line through the relay, don't route the neutral line. Then of course connect the earth and neutral from each connector together. If you don't know what hot, neutral and earth are, now would be a good time to get yourself up to speed on residential wiring.

However, you will want to be a little bit more deliberate and careful than you would with 5V lines, which might include heat shrinking over any soldered connections, and carefully routing the wires inside your enclosure so that they don't move around or come loose and short out. The stiffness of the thicker gauge wire may require a little more forethought and planning while cutting and placing, but you'll figure it out quickly enough.

Lastly, everything needs to be enclosed, you can't just leave it out in the open like you can with 5V.

Comment: With a box that will have a plug or input you _NEED_ to route both wires, because you do not know that in all cases and all countries the plugs will always be plugged in only one way.

Comment: @Asmyldof: the guy is trying to automate something for his apartment, not design a product to be sold in numerous markets.

Comment: Thank you very much this is helpful. Is there a better configuration where I route both wires and make it more robust as whatsisname mentioned? What's the more general way to do this?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: if you want to switch both lines you would need two relays or a double-pole relay.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: "What's the more general way to do this?" Buy or make a network[ed] PDU (power distribution unit).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I mean more general circuit-wise. I'm having fun and learning doing this myself. whatsisname's answer was closer to what I meant.

Comment: @Asmyldof - interesting argument.  How would you reconcile this with the fact that most power strips and other switchable extension cords only switch the hot?  I don't mean to be dismissive - mains safety is a serious thing.  But why do you expect something different from a relay than from a manually actuated switch?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Here in mainland europe mains strips are not allowed to be sold switching only one wire. Both or none.

Comment: @whatsisname That makes no difference. If someone here is asking "Hey this 230V thing, how do I wire that" the burden is on the person answering to take all steps possible to not kill the OP with the advice given.

Comment: @Asmyldof It depends where they live I suppose. Here in New Zealand we have only polarized plugs. In the US non-grounded plugs are not polarized and I would assume that some grounded ones are miswired (if they were upgraded from non-grounded). In the EU even the grounded plugs are non-polarized.

Answer (score 1):

Wire as shown below. Those IEC sockets are rated at 6 A. The relay might be less, so choose a fuse to protect the lower rated device.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdtl10.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>